# Quasar responsive margins not working even with cssAddon enabled

Tags: css, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm using quasar framework v2.6.0 with vite and I read about responsive margins based on the screen size here: [quasar flex-addons](https://quasar.dev/style/spacing#flex-addons).
In my application, I want to make right and left margins smaller or bigger based on the window size, or the platform used.

I have already tried to enable ***'cssAddon:true'*** in my quasar.config file, under the **'framework'** object, but it seems not to work.

```
framework: {
      config: {},
      cssAddon: true,
      // iconSet: 'material-icons', // Quasar icon set
      // lang: 'en-US', // Quasar language pack
      
      // For special cases outside of where the auto-import strategy can have an impact
      // (like functional components as one of the examples),
      // you can manually specify Quasar components/directives to be available everywhere:
      //
      // components: [],
      // directives: [],

      // Quasar plugins
      plugins: [],
    },
```

I'm aware of the screen plugin, but I prefer not to use it for performance purposes, as stated here: [quasar screen plugin](https://quasar.dev/options/screen-plugin/)

Here is a piece of code of my application:

```
<div class="q-mx-xl q-mx-sm-sm q-mb-lg primary-font word-brake-auto-phrase">
    <div class="row q-mx-xl q-mx-sm-sm q-my-xl q-my-sm-sm justify-between">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto col-md-auto">
        <p v-if="!showDescription" class="text-h4">
          Description
        </p>
        <p v-else class="text-h2">Other description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto col-md-auto q-mt-sm">
        <q-btn
          class="button word-brake-auto-phrase bg-white text-black"
          outline
          to="/path"
        >
         To path
        </q-btn>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by myself. I imported the flex-addon module under the ***css*** prop in my quasar.config file, following the instructions [here](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-file#css):

```
module.exports = configure(function (/* ctx */) {
  return {
        /** other config params here **/

        // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-js#css
        css: ['app.scss', '~quasar/src/css/flex-addon.sass'],

       
        /** other config params here **/

  };
};
```

In this way I was able to leverage breakpoints for margins and padding in my quasar application.

Hope this helps!